# Lock VsFTP user to home dir

Tags: linux, ftp

I have been working on this for about an hour and followed many examples but still the new user can get to the whole directory structure, or can't log in at all with message "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()".
My steps were:

```
adduser user1
nano /etc/passwd (changed home dir to /var/www/domain.com and bash to rbash)
nano /etc/vsftpd (uncommented chroot_local_user=YES, chroot_list_enable=YES, chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list)
nano /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list (add a line for user1)
```

I have tried a bunch of different variations of this but it isn't making sense to me. First, lets clarify, what does chroot_local_user=YES actually mean? I only ask because it doesn't seem to be doing anything in the way I expect. Some sites say to switch it to NO.

I am trying to setup a virtual host for my sister's webmaster to access, but don't want him to see my other files for my other sites. Is there a step I missed, or should I just switch to a different ftp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gareth the Red may be absolutely right, I ended up abandoning vsftp because I didn't figure it out before he came along.

I ended up just doing it all through openssh, which had it's own challenges. The thing I never saw in any of the tutorials I will share here.

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Add these lines:
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User sftpuser
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory /home  
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

## Super important this stays /home! If you try /home/sftpuser, it will fail.

The trick in the end was to check the auth.log where I go this error: 
`fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory`

That led me to this page:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot

After I changed the ChrootDirectory to /home, I chmod 750 all the user directories which jailed that user, and then ran this command:

`mount --bind /var/www/example.com /home/sftpuser`

I hope this helps someone, took me several hours to find the right info, would have been a lot less if I had looked in the logs earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to clamp the user to their home directory.  Adding users to `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` grants them an exception from this clamp, therefore your webmaster shouldn't be in there.

You are getting the `500 OOPS` because you have granted write permission on the root of the directory and you have chroots enabled.

You don't need to use a chroot - simply change the home directory of the user to be the website root:

```
usermod -d /var/www/domain.com user1
```

Make sure that your `vsftpd.conf` file contains:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Make sure you've removed (or disabled) any `chroot` lines.